# Core Data background sorting

Tags: sorting, core-data, background, nsmanagedobjectcontext, fetched-property

I have a `Department` entity which has a one-to-many relationship to an `Employee` entity.  During runtime, for each `Department` object I want to maintain a sorted array of `Employee` objects (sorted according to some attribute) which will be used as a model in various view objects.

From what I read there are two ways to represent the sorted array:

**Rep1**: defining a fetched property in `Department` (sorting is done by Core Data);

**Rep2:** maintaining an instance variable **`sortedEmployees`** (`NSArray` of `Employee` objects) in Department (sorting is done by my code).

Now my real problem is, when the app starts up I have a large number of `Departments` and `Employees` to fetch from the persistent store.  I want to perform the sorting in the background so as not to block the UI.

I have tried several methods which all ended up in futility:

**Method1** (using **Rep1**): In background threads (using an `NSOperationQueue`), fetch all `Departments`, then execute each one's fetched property.  Then back in the main thread, find the corresponding `Department` object in the main thread's managed object context (**MOC**) (by **NSManagedObjectID**) and use the fetched property.
Problem with Method1: The fetched property in the main thread's Department object isn't populated even after the background Department's fetch is done, which means that it's re-fetched in the main thread Department!  This defeats the whole purpose of background fetch.  Am I wrong in assuming that a fetched property, once fetched, exists in all MOCs?

**Method2** (using **Rep2**): In background threads (using an `NSOperationQueue`), fetch all `Departments`, then compute each one's `sortedEmployees` array.  Then back in the main thread, find the corresponding Department object in the main thread's **MOC** (by **NSManagedObjectID**) and *set the aforementioned array to this object*.
Problem with Method2: The objects in the `sortedEmployees` array are `Employee` objects belonging to the background thread's **MOC**.  When the main thread attempts to access them later, crash would occur with something like `"NSManagedObject with ID ... has been invalidated."`  This is because each thread must have its own MOC (and its associated managed objects).

So how does one sort managed objects in the background at all, if the managed objects cannot exist across thread boundaries?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pius,

You aren't missing anything. You just need to convert your sorted array to the new MOC. Here's a fragment:

```
NSMutableArray *ma = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: array.count];

for (mo in array) {

    [ma addObject: [moc objectWithID: mo.objectID]];
}
return ma;
```

That will migrate your array. As I understand it, this is an efficient process. Furthermore, you can depend upon the row cache for high performance access to properties.

Andrew

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate what you mean by depending upon the row cache?  What row cache?

Comment: Also, in which thread should I perform your aforementioned array migration?  In the case of main thread, won't "mo" be invalidated and thus err when you access mo.objectID?  In the case of background thread, won't accessing [moc objectWithID:...] be problematic since moc belongs to the main thread?

Comment: Pius, the row cache is maintained by the persistent store coordinator. It is an automatic performance optimization. You don't maintain it -- Core Data does. I normally convert the IDs when I'm on the target thread. Andrew P.S. If you liked this answer, please remember to select it as the "correct" answer.